# Verwendung von „Herrschaften“ je nach Alter

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Die Nutzung des Nomens *Herrschaften* für Menschen verwirrt mich etwas. Laut [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Herrschaft) bedeutet es

> *Herrschaft*. Plural. Veraltend und mitunter ironisch gebraucht: vornehme Anrede für eine Gruppe von Personen (insbesondere gemischten Geschlechts)

Wen kann man denn Herrschaften nennen? Nur Gruppen von Menschen gemischten Geschlechts – wie Damen und Herren – **unabhängig vom Alter**? (*Herrschaften* wirkt irgendwie auf mich, als ob es für ältere Leute wäre, daher die Frage.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Der Gebrauch von "Herrschaften" ist tatsächlich heute nur noch selten. Außer in ironischen Wendungen kann man es aber noch manchmal hören, wenn eine aufgesetzte oder übertriebene Höflichkeit beabsichtigt wurde.

Beispiele:

> - In einem vornehmen und teuren Restaurant wendet sich der schon etwas ergraute Oberkellner an eine Gesellschaft: "Wünschen die Herrschaften vielleicht noch einen Aperitif?".
> - Ein Immobilienmakler führt eine Gruppe von Kaufinteressenten durch ein Anwesen und bedeutet: "Möchten sich die Herrschaften jetzt noch im Garten umsehen?".
> - Ein nicht mehr ganz junger Alleinunterhalter bittet die Hochzeitsgäste mit folgenden Worten auf die Tanzfläche: "Keine Müdigkeit meine Herrschaften, jetzt ist Damenwahl!"

Im Singular wird *Herrschaft* noch weiterhin verwendet, um eine Regierung oder eine Befehlsgewalt (meist in nicht-demokratischer Form) auszudrücken:

> Nach dem Sturz des Regimes übernimmt nun das Militär die Herrschaft über das Land.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, in principle it is used for "Damen und Herren", but it would not sound weird (to me) if by coincidence the people addressed were only ladies or only gentlemen. It does sound quite archaic though, that's why - especially when used for or by younger people - it might be perceived as slightly ironic.

Note that in the old days "Herrschaften" was also used by servants to talk about their bosses like

```
Die Herrschaften kommen erst am Abend wieder nach Hause.
```

In this use, "Herrschaften" also expresses (higher) hierarchy. You may still find uses like this in many novels.

Comment: Warum schreibst Du denn auf Englisch?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Ist mir nicht aufgefallen. Nachteil hat es ja zum Glück keinen, da es die Antwort für mehr Leser zugänglich macht.

Comment: Stimmt, ich fand es nur lustig, weil ja die Frage bereits auf Deutsch war. Ging mir aber auch schon so :-)

Answer (score 1):

Herrschaft means the one that has the power over something.

So you use it to express deference or fake deference. Like when you talk to a bunch of lazy kids. "Würden sich die Herrschaften dazu bequemen wollen zu Tisch zu kommen?"

This would mean that the kids have the power and the parent (father) trys to remind them politely of attending the family dinner table.

Of course this is reverse psychology. Same with waiters and other service personnel. If they wanted to they could make your day a living hell. They won't since you have their money as a customer. So they are deferential to you. Or at least they put on the appearance of being deferential.

Answer (score 1):

Der Ausdruck "meine Herrschaften" ist heutzutage vor allem noch in Süddeutschland gebräuchlich. Insbesondere bei sehr formellen Anreden oder Anschreiben (bspw. Brief, E-Mail) ist es absolut legitim diesen Ausdruck zu gebrauchen.